# Scale bar default location in QGIS 2.18

Tags: print-composer, scale-bar, default, qgis-2.18

When adding a scale bar in the print composer, by default there is a gap between the scale bar and it's frame :

[image]

How can I move the sacle bar (blue circle) to the Lower left corner (red circle) ?

[image]

For example, in ArcGIS the scale bar doesn't have a gap between the scale bar and it frame

[image]

Comment: Why do you care for that gap or margin?

Comment: I set the bar at the bottom left of the map- and the gap disturbed me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the Scalebar property Display > Box margin to 0 and drag the bottom frame border up to fit the scalebar.

[image]

The last lower left gap you cannot get rid of. It's the margin of the number 1. Margin can only be control vertically, between the scale numbers and the scalebar, but not horizontally.